# Anyone using Junit4 with cpsuite-1.2.5 and EasyMock?

Tags: java, classpath, junit4, easymock

We are using ClassPathSuite to simplify our testing:
http://www.johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp

This works extremely well.  The only issue we are encountering is with EasyMock.  EasyMock works fine if we run a single test class in isolation.  But if we try to run all of our tests using ClassPathSuite EasyMock does not work correctly:

```
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.*;
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@ExcludeCategory(SlowTest.class)
@SuiteClasses( {AllCITests.class})
public class FastTestSuite {

}
```

No exceptions occur, however the following code appears to not function as expected (we never get back what we define in the andReturn:)

```
EasyMock.expectLastCall().andReturn(somethingElse);
```

Has anyone seen & solved this issue?

Comment: Have you tried running multiple classes including the one that is failing without using cpsuite? As I´m looking right now it is a management tool for tests so I don´t think it bothers in any way to EasyMock

Comment: If I run using normal jUnit4 I don't have any issues with the EasyMock tests.  I run the same three classes and same tests but get different results compared to when I use cpsuite.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to have nothing to do with ClassPathSuite or EasyMock.  Instead it was caused by the use of Singletons in our code.  We had a specific scenario where EasyMock was not being called because a Singleton already existed for the object we were trying to mock.